# Drush pm-list needs a higher bootstrap level to run

Tags: drush

I am getting this error when trying to run pm-list. I am in the Drupal folder, not at the root, on Mamp Pro on my Mac using OS X El Capitan. I have tried setting the host from localhost to 127.0.0.1, tried adding paths to the .bash_profile. Not sure what else to do. Following is the output upon entering pm-list:

```
The drush command 'pm-list' could not be executed.                 
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.        
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to:
 Drupal version         :  7.43
 Site URI               :  http://default
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1
 Database port          :
 Database username      :  interdev
 Database name          :  interdev
 PHP executable         :  /usr/local/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin
 Drush script           :  /Users/studio17/Sites/interdev/vendor/dr
                       ush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.11
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /Users/studio17/Sites/interdev
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
 Site path              :  sites/default
```